# Specifiying asp.net action inside the JS code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller-action

I am building a html table inside my JS code and I need to have something like

```
<a href="link goes here">click on me</a>
```

The inside of the `a href` needs to point to a controller action. The question is how do I do inside my JS?

Comment: Could you post 'your JS code'? to clarify what it is you want exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the controller and action to the href.

```
<a href='/ControllerName/ActionName'>click</a>
```